# Weird bug on background scrolling

Tags: php, html, css

So I was trying to fix my background so it would scroll with the page, I did a lot of things to get it working but nothing seems to work. When I removed the include for my header.php it worked perfect. The weird thing is that if I click on a dropdown menu my background scrolls, and when I don't click on it it doesn’t scroll. If you click on it the background is suposed to move.

This is the link where you can find the bug :http://willevz90.ninety.axc.nl/traoc.php?username=30 Just scroll first. You will see that it is not scrolling. Then click on tracker (in the menu) and scroll. The following code is being used

Header.php : http://willevz90.ninety.axc.nl/header.txt

This is a small code from traoc.php because the other things are just php

traoc.php : (Same code as header.txt just change header.txt to traoc.txt)

~Kev

Comment: You should add the *relevant* code here and preferably add a fiddle. Also this has nothing to do with php, so please don't use the php tag.

Comment: @HamZa Yes this is php otherwise i should not use the include ;) + when i remove the include it works. So yes this has something to do with php

Comment: my bad, re-added the php tag

Comment: @HamZa No problem and a fiddle should not work because its a to large peace of code.

Comment: The problem with this is that it's not useful for future users since the "bug" will disappear. Putting this story aside. I tested your site and it works as expected. I mean how can the background scroll while it's fixed ?

Comment: @nave-tseva It did not work 

Also on including the header.php the code for background won't scroll only on removing the include it work's

Comment: I updated my code, pleas review it..

Comment: @NaveTseva tested it but it should not spread on the page i also think i sayd my question wrong : the background should be fixed and the table etc should move on it. Sorry for any mis unerstanding.

Comment: Do you want something like this?? : http://css-tricks.com/examples/FullPageBackgroundImage/css-1.php

Comment: @NaveTseva Yes! but that only works for me when i remove the included header. But i want it working with the header included

Comment: Well, there sre in this link a lot of ways to do it. I hope that you will get it.. http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/